# Pydev: Validate python source files against a custom grammar

Tags: eclipse, pydev

We use a Jython interpreter embeded within a server application and a client (Eclipse RCP) that uses Pydev to edit scripts. We have augmented the Python syntax in a few distinct cases, for example `pos x`; this is translated to `pos(x)` and then passed into the interpreter.

Would it be possible to define a custom grammar based on Jython, with some modifications, and get Pydev to parse source files using this instead of the true grammar? [This page](https://www.pydev.org/developers_grammar.html) gives some insight into grammars but it's not clear whether possible to attach a new grammar at runtime (e.g. via an extension point) or whether a custom build of Pydev would be required (which is undesirable).

Comment: Hello @joeshannon, this is not currently possible. To do that you'd need to change PyDev itself to accept grammars from extension points. If you're interested in adding that support, please contact me at fabiofz at gmail dot com so that we can discuss how it should be done.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment, sorry for my slow response. I think that we would interested in doing this provided we have some time to do so. I may contact you for discussion at some point in the future.